# Extracting one table from HTML using XSLTProcessor

Tags: php, xslt

I am trying to get the contents of a table with the class sticky-enabled in XML format.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

// Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$out = $xml->load("collection.html");

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('collection.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

$xml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print_r($xml);

?>
```

And the collection.html HTML is:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>

<table class="sticky-enabled">
 <thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Location</th><th>Tracking Event</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="odd"><td>16-04-2013</td><td>19:20</td><td>International Hub</td><td>Forwarded for export</td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td>16-04-2013</td><td>18:53</td><td>International Hub</td><td>Received and processed</td> </tr>
 <tr class="odd"><td>15-04-2013</td><td>17:28</td><td>Manchester Piccadilly Depot</td><td>Collected from customer</td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td>15-04-2013</td><td>00:00</td><td>WDM Online</td><td></td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And finally collection.xsl is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <output>
    <xsl:for-each select="table[@class='sticky-enabled']/tbody/tr">
      <tracking>
        <date><xsl:value-of select="td[1]" /></date>
        <time><xsl:value-of select="td[2]" /></time>
        <event><xsl:value-of select="td[3]" /></event>
        <extra><xsl:value-of select="td[4]" /></extra>        
      </tracking> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </output>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I run this then $xml is empty. If I edit collection.html and remove the first and last tables (i.e. just leaving the one I am trying to access) then it works. I suspect the problem is therefore with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="table[@class='sticky-enabled']/tbody/tr">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "XML" is not well-formed. So, it can't be parsed and transformed with the XSLT. An XML document must have a single document element. You have three `<table>` elements that are siblings. Removing the other tables results in a well-formed XML file that can be transformed.

Try wrapping the tables with an XML element.

For example:

```
<doc>
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>

<table class="sticky-enabled">
 <thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Location</th><th>Tracking Event</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="odd"><td>16-04-2013</td><td>19:20</td><td>International Hub</td><td>Forwarded for export</td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td>16-04-2013</td><td>18:53</td><td>International Hub</td><td>Received and processed</td> </tr>
 <tr class="odd"><td>15-04-2013</td><td>17:28</td><td>Manchester Piccadilly Depot</td><td>Collected from customer</td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td>15-04-2013</td><td>00:00</td><td>WDM Online</td><td></td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
  </table>
<doc>
```

Then adjust your stylesheet to account for the change to the structure, matching on the document element instead of root node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each select="table[@class='sticky-enabled']/tbody/tr">
                <tracking>
                    <date><xsl:value-of select="td[1]" /></date>
                    <time><xsl:value-of select="td[2]" /></time>
                    <event><xsl:value-of select="td[3]" /></event>
                    <extra><xsl:value-of select="td[4]" /></extra>        
                </tracking> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </output>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I appreciate it. I should have mentioned that I am writing this code so I can ultimately extract data from a table on an external site. I don't have any control over this table.

Comment: Perhaps I can extract the sticky-enabled table via another method and then use DOMDocument to process the table?

Comment: How are you extracting the tables? Is the entire document or body well-formed? You could transform that. If you can extract just the table you want to transform, then that would work as well.